# Reload configuration for a package when using req-package

Tags: init-file

I'm using `req-package` to manage per-package configuration in my `init.el`. All works fine when in stable state. Let's say I need to modify it. For example, I might want to add a new key mapping. I find the `req-package` sexp for a particular mode, I add the necessary change to the `:config` element, restart Emacs and all is good.

My question is, is there a way to do this without restarting Emacs? Basically, I'd like to re-run a particular `req-package` sexp or in other words reload / reinitialize a particular package.

I know I can run the commands separately, but running the whole `req-package` does not seem to have any effect, which I presume is because `req-package` already knows the package was loaded / initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this difficulty as well.  Once you've evaluated the modified `(req-package somepackage ...)` form call:

```
(req-package-eval 'somepackage)
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @ebpa! I wish it did this automatically on req-package eval...

Comment: @icyrock.com I bet it will be added soon.  You can track it here: https://github.com/edvorg/req-package/issues/27